# Analogue of `std::pair` with mutable members?

Tags: c++, boost, mutable, std-pair, boost-multi-index

I am implementing analogue of `std::map` called `expiring_map` which is based on `boost::multi_index::multi_index_container`. Idea is simple: when there is new insert to the `expiring_map` there will be check up for expired elements and removal if they are present.

I want to have some similar interface to the `std::map`:

```cpp
template <class Clock, class Key, class T, class Compare = std::less<Key>>
class expiring_map
{
    explicit expiring_map(clock_type cl, duration expiry_duration);

    void insert_or_assign(value_type v);

    iterator begin();
    iterator end();
    const_iterator begin() const;
    const_iterator end() const;

    // size(), clear() and lookup-methods are omitted for simplicity
};
```

I also want for next code to be valid

```cpp
    auto clock = std::make_shared<std::chrono::steady_clock>();
    expiring_map<decltype(clock), int, std::string> m{ clock, std::chrono::seconds{ 1 } };
    m.insert_or_assign({ 1, "value" });
    const auto b = m.begin();
    auto v = std::move(b->second);
    EXPECT_EQ(v, "value");
    EXPECT_TRUE(b->second.empty());
```

Since all elements for `boost::multi_index::multi_index_container` indices are considered non-mutable the only way (according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10510994/15751315) answer) for me to reach desired results is to specify as `value_type` of `expiring_map` next struct

```cpp
struct value_type {
    const Key first;
    mutable T second;
};
```

Because `using value_type = std::pair<const Key, mutable T>` is not valid c++ expression as keyword `mutable` is about storage duration and not about the type. From https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cv

> The C++ language grammar treats mutable as a storage-class-specifier, rather than a type qualifier, but it does not affect storage class or linkage.

#### Question

My problem with this solution is my `const` overloads for `begin()` and `end()` are not really const and next code is compiling:

```cpp
using subject_type = ::expiring_map<std::shared_ptr<std::chrono::steady_clock>, int, std::string>;

void foo(const subject_type& s) {
   s.begin()->second = "new";
}
```

How can I change my implementation for const overloads of `begin()` and `end()` to achieve compilation error but preserve these methods (to still be able to iterate with range-based-for using `const expiring_map&`)?

[Link](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGErqSuADJ4DJgAcj4ARpjEIADM0gAOqAqETgwe3r7%2BpClpjgIhYZEsMXGJtpj2hQxCBEzEBFk%2BflwBdpgOGfWNBMUR0bEJ0goNTS057bbj/aGDZcOJAJS2qF7EyOwc5vGhyN5YANQm8W5jxKHAp9gmGgCCu/uHmCdnUaipBAD0hLFMRGI3wIxEMCn4xBYAH0/qDAQA6BBJJI3O6PMx7BgHLzHU5uD5fb4sLy0RwwhhYVREzCLYiI5Goh5PLEvN74z5jIkksmhSnfEhYYiYdDkyn0lHxW5MjHPHGvPEEznE0l4UWYKlKACOXkYWxFvPV4sZ6Mx2Nx7w5P2VPIp6qhaEETHmdKREqlJtl5rcANQLDwpklaOZZvlZ2QCGIAlQxuDrLxXkctEIAE8bkdvt8jmN0CAQEkncQgzKWXK2cACJhOeXKwRETHiyGyyxUMgANbfYDNtt1wNMh7MNgKfNbIMAdisffuGaO9wYR3VSTwlyMRxYTCSRxiCCYADdK0cmAoD0chcASY1V%2BvSEcAO6EBBHAgIV5KPeg2jz1RbJK1BQgNHTho8JHAAYiQ85vsm86CMQUGoFQj7PpeG6EEeoRKE0GSPngbApKEBBHHgR4KLuwrwgBmZcMBADqz5zuhsSOCuRDHkkQrqkRFaCNBILJteqGEQwGG1NhuGoPhhFHl4SToACZEUUcZjAfcVAVsQgnCVhByYIY0lHPBn6LkK6CERWLBoUeSSxBCbDoORDxmUkBgVmyByHkebi0C2rbXm5ChHgA0pgfFHH5R4ACq%2BQY/lHB4LD5kKbwACJZgQOYgPQ/l4kFqaBr29xhYZS5XFCa4oky45okkXhREmyD/n2ACcXhpMxOGYFCeHcacKXZrm4aRgwqC5mMOnoMm9peW2uaOGwnXiYIpwTo8GjNa1wBHOgGwAlhPWpelA1RiNFZMONk3ebmW1whkS1BqtLVXEcrbBVCBDJlZyVHDlt1NQ9K5lVZIpvR9e3hT9K2NdOfV5gWeIOmMX3BdexINLVrxg5KoWGGAHAETERwtcKRzPkKDUQ9OsSRnEj7va8A6vOgqD7kNBFiF5N6pSQTDAK8hUsfjQ5dHgNDCndkOZn9G07mIOqvbTn3Q/mS5wwICM5cjCZMGjRwY7c8TLXc4tHMbJum2b5sW5bZsmAArO6hsXF4DhHNL3gdcD8qVU1hvwwROVHDQxBjODhuGyjWv0DrWZdAI6Dg5bVCXK4m6fB%2BqBWXCJA9T1EC%2By7Mvu7T5gAGxHLQvmqwRruyx7JcnssJzjiemAEBsc60PCgcI9n8QpXSXcESXdcd0oDomT3ffwqPsdLY3SViyYo7z/rYuS0cQ1YHLIO9/tuZK4WZyzR1XUENe1eF1ZqIr7961ZngABeF%2Bhr1aUjQ/7sh/dt8HN5W/P7FU1Wyfwho7Z2597S%2BgSp7CwKdPD6Qzj6YgEBli50rvnN2f9h4IAUBXISVcC6YLMKXYg2CG550XjAoUrdiBzjilAihi8koQFoNgzuS4xjXhIQoNhQcCDLFnowuewDDZr3VCCJgDgoQLiXB1WSLk9qKgILma0qoDTqBAGwWkeIN5P2vEfea%2BFrwlx0X/XMA8r4Gy/o9MRoJJHgI9p9RRyjuSqNtOozR5RtEYF0egmutMjFEJMR7EaMcKQWNXrfLwtpiC0GTCVBxCjLTOJVGqdxLjUkQMdM6PEC9VpBP8bkxqTiNHpLUbmNRwooRRFym4QphtikqNSSE7UupRZnDqatepSSSkpLKSABo1wzigLxhNaR10BAxk6VMxqNxSAdKKd0xpfSBSxEqVEvALScne2mV0r4ySbSUhmtzPEwzNwTXsUXSUcztkzOmTYiRBAoQXKstc%2B4VsLbgLQPFRomB5mTNuTM/Koc8qWIhmvWEiDPpYAOB7CADSmDPVeqCISNkYRqUQXie5diCG10lBAaG0LaCu3jNE2J8TLnYGQfCRyzlXg8wIAqc5OKKVUpiMAUIyDlj8Ovm8k2a9fZov%2BICT6ELATCNWguOqhAirLmAKVdcudAF/1CuXTa20RJjImldHaAh%2BE3JACq3%2B%2BLX4aNQHuRVXLCnXk1VCbVtQoQQBtXajIeqIYMKXndCGO5xImQYk0KEJAoTuTwMABgEBnmvB3A3BhNy85MATKgdeqAOZ7R/m2KEABaG4Q0bzIM/gCuNCaZWyLkp9HNJxLAyq1eqjIUJ82G3jUQOuKzjIK0BNzDq1KaROVLfSxlTzmWXzxdyyxBa0GNsTbbCw7NYjXmkhnW2KU9otrIpgbUYgoTIp5uGkdhThZHDhanAO6wKSfRnepMAYA9rztiLPfgUT0DRq9m66Z0k5HH3YqoTiJVGC8QgAAKnPdeHN15obNnNTuKeoTH27puYI6oShG6jtDqtFddlu0GC2FCBA%2BFmHJtncW21clQMmvA5gHdsGX0zI9ZOFDjUM6ou0rpJIAaqBSNUEZSpfxzIQBzZR0ONGVoQ1FeBNlHKn2UJbm3WBYxlEIvdsi8EJBoQiYPm4LFjyI03GNVzHmUIu3xVpUcPt7wmUYNxZS5Y8IxNhstfrIRTVVPQXQMgpDzdqFznhYi8RKLlOCszmpjTA7zMsrGLpztNLe0t37Vp4d8JXCcoEYJn2ld/OQps658hTcqHSa8wpsEqLVOYtUOI7FIWh2UrC6CPTBme0uRM/iMzfiKusswOy2zI6HMQwFU5hLZC0EUPc7lxZ8mkUFb80Vs4QXYuVfbTVyL9XoumeC8135cW%2BudcYZ6tieBpYVjJobb1eATJvrkp1T936jBSJgsmVBeCk2b1rkQnisE9HtQMdxEDyFAbKrCDeFbmAJOFInXXLUOosREz2lVjt%2BmFt0qW419jRkdUMG0/x6ZhaWJg9afqQeO9scQ7sqp16qBHU3fRwCgnep4TNnwFQW7VOuOnxODbKwRDF28e8YQ0uOigdwbyd4nh3cd7lusFW21NaBB1p5XRw2OioNjwV7HNt6UyO8cwP98%2BFOBNJW16tRndkhRTTkvitd4Pqd9dA2bnHaLtfJaakdkyDG/NMYYNJVjSOZG45pAoCA%2BiT5JpvHzqjIPnsG7beF2HGGosMuW2MlHaP62rUx4mg3VS2uhAVtbwn1mM%2B2aT41FP0cWmE%2Bu%2BPfH2eLcUjzTLjH46i2whJ1CAezehQKAfFDk1N7iBVJPS5%2BZeWxu%2BchGlsVU2Su2MeWMktFZtNp5s6sAfI3vOKcK%2Bisf6mJ8PM90KIjs%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%2BqPKBrBqhoQAXEBJmCeBxzRGMKUamyKFMETSqFDKVHVGYKBiVRLwQB3FlT/EmzYAAAayg2Abg4UUI4UAAEvcOFDCbsZQTNDWFcLmNgPQGwIIAoPcEKPimCVsbTLmFpuOAEBWl8bQD8Q4UvHZjccbGiKbBTKoKwE5K8InL6KlBIq2PpG%2BFQOzLySbEXlEJ9LCeuMEf0asSbMMTuGMaaualEGEREfCcbEiSiWiVCNgAAIrhqfHfGOHxwInImononhQABKcglKupNwER8W8Ub0iWMugmHAqwtAnANsvAfgHAWgpAw0HAtSlgYuCg6wmw8oGIPApASi4ZAZqwrYIANsGg%2BgnAkgoZmgvAUZvAf4uZaZWgqwcAsASA6oXQCaZAFAEAjQwACgyghg1QQgCAyaYZKZXyi4zkGQ7ZYQtAXZPZRZpA/ZdAwwwAAAHDbJOZAtOcQOEKwNsLwFOfQMQAAPIJhjk3hhkRl1nIBUmtmcC8DHn1D4Bhm8D8CCAiBiDsBSAyCCCKAqDqDpmkC6ABAGBGAoDWDWD6B4BRB/iwD0wgCKKkBvicBcDFwFlVngXACfDAD0AVgcLQXcBcCVmrDpy/icAZrZg9SmCxmWBcCjjFlviXBYCgXIJrAbBbB6DZihDDmdndkHkwW8AgiYDsC5k3ighJAcWBnBmFmflRnYCqD1nCqqCznFwZpwXGbIDIBHCznwg2wHoxls42BHC4CEDgS7BcDLCcVFlcqkBZk5l5kcAFmkAsASAaC5mHnFnnm2AgDlnGVCUcBmAiURklmpluVQWxBpDOCSBAA) to godbolt with current implementation and tests

#### What have I tried

I have tried using different extractor like

```cpp
    struct extract_value_type_as_const_ref {
        [[nodiscard]] std::pair<const Key&, const T&> operator()(const node_type& n) const { return { n.second.first, n.second.second }; }
    };

    using const_iterator = decltype(boost::make_transform_iterator<extract_value_type_as_const_ref>(std::declval<underlying_type>().template get<by_value_type>().cbegin()));
```

but `::testing::ElementsAre` requires for result of `*(map.begin())` to be convertible to `value_type` but I really don't want to copy all of constructors of `std::pair` for my `value_type`

Comment: For those following along at home on a Macintosh (rather than the link to Matt Godbolt's online compiler), you may need `brew install googletest` and `clang++ -std=c++17 -lgtest -lgmock a.cpp`.

Comment: Can you do this: `const_iterator begin() const = delete;`?

Comment: @Eljay, unfortunately, no. `::testing::ElementsAre` requires const overloads. I definitely can live without `::testing::ElementsAre`, but if someone tomorrow will have to iterate through my container using range-based-for, there will be unexpected compilation error

Comment: *How can I change my implementation for const overloads of begin() and end() to achieve compilation error?*  I thought you **wanted** to achieve compilation error.

Comment: @Eljay, yep, you are right, I've updated the question to clarify my desires :)

Comment: `auto v = std::move(b->second);` does not make sense.  `b` is a `std::string`, not a pointer.

Comment: @Eljay, no, it is not, as it is compiles on Compiler Explorer. You can let your compiler check for you with 
`static_assert(std::is_same_v<std::remove_const_t<decltype(b)>, typename subject_type::iterator>);`
or for `b->second`:
`static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(b->second), std::string>);`
or without `static_assert`s by specifying type by yourself:
`std::string v = std::move(b->second);`

Comment: The `auto v = std::move(b->second);` does not compile for me.  I don't think the code that you *want to be valid* will be valid.

Comment: @Eljay, oh, now I get it. There was an error in code snippet in the question as you noticed indeed, my apologies. I've misunderstood your remark since in attached [link](https://godbolt.org/z/xW1rx4or7) correct code was shown. I've edited the question, thank you for your patience

Comment: I would not try to make this implicitly/silently work.  To `value_type`, I'd add a mutating accessor to second, and impose upon the callsite to explicitly access the second value as mutating.  `T& mut_second() const { auto& self = const_cast<value_type&>(*this); return self.second; }`.  That puts all the dynamite in the caller's hands.  (Up to you if `second` should be declared `mutable`, but I don't think so.)  There be dragons here.

Answer (score 0):

The `second` member in your `value_type` should not be `mutable`. This is the fix:

```cpp
struct value_type {
    const Key first;
    T second;
};
```

Making this change makes your assertion on Compiler Explorer pass.

Maybe you've misunderstood something about the `value_type` of maps in general.
A `std::map<Key, Value>` will store a `value_type = std::pair<const Key, Value>`.

- The `Key` has to be `const`. Otherwise, we would be able to mutate the key without also changing the position of the pair in the map, which breaks the data structure.
- The `Value` is **not `mutable`**. A `const std::map` will expose `const value_type&`, and the `Value` stored inside that pair is then also `const`.<sup>1)</sup>

Furthermore, it makes sense that `std::pair<const Key, mutable T>` wouldn't compile. `mutable` is a property of data members (like `private` or `static`), it's not part of the a type.

In general, `mutable` is only meant to be used for data members which have to be mutable under all circumstances, even inside of `const` objects. For example, a `std::mutex` member is typically mutable, because a `const std::mutex` is unusable, and you need to be able to use it regardless.

---

<sup>1)</sup> It is possible that the `Value` stored inside is not a `const` object, but a mutable object. *Technically*, you could still mutate it through `const_cast` then. However, this cannot be relied upon.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience, I've updated the link in the question, added desired test, in which removing `mutable` does not save the situation

Comment: > `mutable` is only meant to be used for data members which have to be mutable under all circumstances,

Yeah, i'm aware, but I want to find a way to be able to modify elements in `boost::multi_index::multi_index_container` using only my iterator without assisting methods like `modify`, `replace` which are offered by `boost`